# CORS and ReactJS using Etsy APIs

Tags: reactjs

I'm a n00b trying to learn React. I'm building a website that uses Etsy's APIs. Registered an app there and everything. They have a page that talks about CORS and proxying here: https://www.etsy.com/developers/documentation/getting_started/jsonp

So for example, I'm trying to do a fetch on a store's listings:

```
fetch('https://openapi.etsy.com/v2/shops/[shopId]/listings/active?api_key=[apiKey]')
```

But that violates the browser's CORS policy. No problem, says the documentation on Etsy. You can always use their proxy: beta-api.etsy.com. So I add that to my package.json file:

```
"proxy": "https://beta-api.etsy.com/"
```

And then I change my fetch line:

```
fetch('/v2/shops/[shopId]/listings/active?api_key=[apiKey]')
```

But CORS is still being violated in the browser.

> Access to fetch at 'https://www.etsy.com/shop/beta-api/v2/shops/[shopId]/listings/active?api_key=[apiKey]' (redirected from 'http://localhost:3000/v2/shops/[shopId]/listings/active?api_key=[apiKey]') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I don't want an opaque response, either, so doing "no-cors" really doesn't help. Does anyone have any recommendations on how I can at least get a local website up and running?

Comment: To resolve this, use the crossOriginLoading setting in development to add the crossorigin attribute to the <script> tags generated for the JSONP requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting that error because your server has set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to restrict cross-domain traffic.  You are sending your request from your localhost so that is considered cross-domain.

If you are able to change your server settings to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` then you can make those requests without a CORS error but I don't suggest doing this.

The best solution would probably be a proxy server.  You can use [cors-anywhere](https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/) heroku app to easily do this.

*Excerpt from Medium Article on this issue*

> The cors-anywhere server is a proxy that adds CORS headers to a
>   request. A proxy acts as an intermediary between a client and server.
>
> In this case, the cors-anywhere proxy server operates in between the
>   frontend web app making the request, and the server that responds with
>   data.
>
> Similar to the Allow-control-allow-origin plugin, it adds the
>   more open Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * header to the response.
>
> Say your frontend is trying to make a GET request to:
>   https://joke-api-strict-cors.appspot.com/jokes/random
>
> But this api does not have a Access-Control-Allow-Origin value 
>   in place that permits the web application domain to access it.
>
> So instead, send your GET request to:
>   https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://joke-api-strict-cors.appspot.com/jokes/random
>
> The proxy server receives the
>   https://joke-api-strict-cors.appspot.com/jokes/random
>
> from the url above. Then it makes the request to get that server’s 
>   response. And finally, the proxy applies the Access-Control-Allow-
>   Origin: * to that original response.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: Hope it helps!   If this answer fixed your problem, please accept by clicking the checkmark to the left of it.  :)   Thanks.   https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: The solution is only for developement purposes. It won't work in production and the application specifically says not to use it because it is only a demo.

Comment: Another free hosted proxy would be to use https://proxy.cors.sh/ instead of the one from herokuapp. I messaged Etsy to know if there is any other way of dealing with the CORS issue
https://blog.grida.co/cors-anywhere-for-everyone-free-reliable-cors-proxy-service-73507192714e